# mysqldump for older mysql version, from mysql 8 to mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Are there any known risks if I use mysql dump tool to backup MySql databases older versions? For example, if I use mysql dump 8 on a production machine to backup MySql 5.7 databases.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why no one has answered this valid question. Let's fix this.

First, a disclaimer: the best practice will always be to use the same version of `mysqldump` as the MySQL database. Even if there is a difference in the minor version, it is still recommended to use the same version. Having said that, let's dig into the question.

In general, the short answer is: it depends. Now, the long version. There are two issues. First, `mysqldump`, while dumping the data, collects some additional information. For example, the latest version of Percona Server for MySQL 8.0 (8.0.30) that we tested, executes following query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"') FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'mysql' AND TABLE_NAME = 'columns_priv';
```

Obviously, this will not work on MySQL 5.7, where there is no such table in the `information_schema` database. It does not mean that older versions of `mysqldump` would not work. Maybe you are lucky and your `mysqldump` does not use such query? Another potential issue is that `mysqldump` introduces some commands into dump file:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.30-22, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database:
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       8.0.30-22

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!50606 SET @OLD_INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC=@@INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC */;
/*!50606 SET GLOBAL INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC=OFF */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!50717 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rocksdb_has_p_s_session_variables FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'performance_schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'session_variables' */;
/*!50717 SET @rocksdb_get_is_supported = IF (@rocksdb_has_p_s_session_variables, 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rocksdb_is_supported FROM performance_schema.session_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME=\'rocksdb_bulk_load\'', 'SELECT 0') */;
/*!50717 PREPARE s FROM @rocksdb_get_is_supported */;
/*!50717 EXECUTE s */;
/*!50717 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s */;
/*!50717 SET @rocksdb_enable_bulk_load = IF (@rocksdb_is_supported, 'SET SESSION rocksdb_bulk_load = 1', 'SET @rocksdb_dummy_bulk_load = 0') */;
/*!50717 PREPARE s FROM @rocksdb_enable_bulk_load */;
/*!50717 EXECUTE s */;
/*!50717 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s */;
SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;

--
-- GTID state at the beginning of the backup
-- (origin: Binlog_snapshot_gtid_executed)
--

SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '5339ac74-6ccb-11ed-9c89-080027a26bfd:1-6';

--
-- Position to start replication or point-in-time recovery from
--
```

They are tagged in comments with the MySQL version that supports them so, theoretically speaking, this should be background-compatible. Still, some of them, depending on the flags you used to execute `mysqlbinlog` with, are not commented.

In the example above you can see GTID_PURGED global variable is set. It might be problematic to execute `mysqldump` on the database where GTID are not used. As you can see, it is hard to answer the question definitively - 8.0 `myqldump` used on 5.7? Probably not. 5.7 on 5.6? Not sure, maybe that would work. In general, as mentioned in the beginning, the best practice is to use the same version across the board.